# Why are Go sockets slower than C++ sockets?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, go, network-programming

I benchmarked a simple socket ping pong test in Go and C++. The client begins by sending 0 to the server. The server increments whatever number it gets and sends it back to the client. The client echos the number back to the server, and stops once the number is 1,000,000.

Both the client and the server are on the same computer, so I use a Unix socket in both cases. (I also tried same-host TCP sockets, which showed a similar result).

The Go test takes 14 seconds, whereas the C++ test takes 8 seconds. This is surprising to me because I have run a fair number of Go vs. C++ benchmarks, and generally Go is as performant as C++ as long as I don't trigger the garbage collector.

I am on a Mac, though commenters have also reported that the Go version is slower on Linux.

Wondering if I am missing a way to optimize the Go program or if there are just inefficiencies under the hood.

Below are the commands I run to carry out the test, along with the test results. All code files are pasted at the bottom of this question.

Run Go server:

```
$ rm /tmp/go.sock
$ go run socketUnixServer.go
```

Run Go client:

```
$ go build socketUnixClient.go; time ./socketUnixClient

real    0m14.101s
user    0m5.242s
sys     0m7.883s
```

Run C++ server:

```
$ rm /tmp/cpp.sock
$ clang++ -std=c++11 tcpServerIncUnix.cpp -O3; ./a.out
```

Run C++ client:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 tcpClientIncUnix.cpp -O3; time ./a.out

real    0m8.690s
user    0m0.835s
sys     0m3.800s
```

Code files

Go server:

```
// socketUnixServer.go

package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("unix", "/tmp/go.sock")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Listen error: ", err)
    }

    c, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connected with client!")

    readbuf := make([]byte, 4)
    writebuf := make([]byte, 4)
    for {
        c.Read(readbuf)
        clientNum := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(readbuf)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(writebuf, clientNum+1)

        c.Write(writebuf)
    }
}
```

Go client:

```
// socketUnixClient.go

package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "encoding/binary"
)

const N = 1000000

func main() {
    c, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/go.sock")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Dial error", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    readbuf := make([]byte, 4)
    writebuf := make([]byte, 4)

    var currNumber uint32 = 0
    for currNumber < N {
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(writebuf, currNumber)
        c.Write(writebuf)

        // Read the incremented number from server
        c.Read(readbuf[:])
        currNumber = binary.BigEndian.Uint32(readbuf)
    }
}
```

C++ server:

```
// tcpServerIncUnix.cpp

// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming
// #include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Big Endian (network order)
unsigned int fromBytes(unsigned char b[4]) {
    return b[3] | b[2]<<8 | b[1]<<16 | b[0]<<24;
}

void toBytes(unsigned int x, unsigned char (&b)[4]) {
    b[3] = x;
    b[2] = x>>8;
    b[1] = x>>16;
    b[0] = x>>24;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_un saddr;
    int saddrlen = sizeof(saddr);
    unsigned char recv_buffer[4] = {0};
    unsigned char send_buffer[4] = {0};

    server_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    saddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(saddr.sun_path, "/tmp/cpp.sock", sizeof(saddr.sun_path));
    saddr.sun_path[sizeof(saddr.sun_path)-1] = '\0';
    bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));

    listen(server_fd, 3);

    // Accept one client connection
    new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, (socklen_t*)&saddrlen);
    printf("Connected with client!\n");

    // Note: if /tmp/cpp.sock already exists, you'll get the Connected with client!
    // message before running the client. Delete this file first.

    unsigned int x = 0;

    while (true) {
        valread = read(new_socket, recv_buffer, 4);
        x = fromBytes(recv_buffer);
        toBytes(x+1, send_buffer);

        write(new_socket, send_buffer, 4);
    }
}
```

C++ client:

```
// tcpClientIncUnix.cpp

// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming
// #include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Big Endian (network order)
unsigned int fromBytes(unsigned char b[4]) {
    return b[3] | b[2]<<8 | b[1]<<16 | b[0]<<24;
}

void toBytes(unsigned int x, unsigned char (&b)[4]) {
    b[3] = x;
    b[2] = x>>8;
    b[1] = x>>16;
    b[0] = x>>24;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sock, valread;
    struct sockaddr_un saddr;
    int opt = 1;
    int saddrlen = sizeof(saddr);

    // We'll be passing uint32's back and forth
    unsigned char recv_buffer[4] = {0};
    unsigned char send_buffer[4] = {0};

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    saddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(saddr.sun_path, "/tmp/cpp.sock", sizeof(saddr.sun_path));
    saddr.sun_path[sizeof(saddr.sun_path)-1] = '\0';

    // Accept one client connection
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) != 0) {
        throw("connect failed");
    }

    int n = 1000000;

    unsigned int currNumber = 0;
    while (currNumber < n) {
        toBytes(currNumber, send_buffer);
        write(sock, send_buffer, 4);

        // Read the incremented number from server
        valread = read(sock, recv_buffer, 4);
        currNumber = fromBytes(recv_buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: My results: `go version devel +90dca98d33 Thu Dec 20 22:11:45 2018 +0000 linux/amd64`  `time ./client`  `real  0m7.653s  user  0m1.803s  sys  0m5.150s`

Comment: `go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64; time go client real    0m7.242s`, `clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4; time c++ client   real    0m4.942s` ... nowhere near as drastic discrepancy.

Comment: My large linux discrepancy may be related to that particular machine then. I am also seeing 30% slower on Mac which is similar to your results tink. I’ll change the wording of the question to ask about this discrepancy

Comment: My results: `g++ (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0`  `time ./a.out  real 0m6.013s  user 0m0.253s  sys  0m4.564s`

Comment: @rampatowl: Your results are not reproducible.

Comment: @peterSO Hey Peter, it does look my linux results were wonky. But it seems we’re all getting 20-30% slower results for the Go program now. I edited my question so that it addresses this discrepancy rather than the original 3x difference. Still curious about why there is a discrepancy is here at all when normally Go is competitive with C++.

Comment: Comparing two languages like this is virtually meaningless. The functionality may be the same, but implementation differences will skewer the results.  This is in the same ballpark as `my db is x times faster than the competitor x,y and z`, which may be true for certain workloads, but tells you nothing about real life performance, stability, maintainability and ease of use.

Comment: @tink out of curiosity, what are the specs of the machine you're using? I can only get to 11s on a 3GHz AWS linux box.

Comment: It's my workstation, a Dell optiplex, i7-6700 @ 3.4GHz, 16GB. @rampatowl

Comment: This is totally in C, and C is not C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I confirm that the Go programs from this question do run noticeably slower than the C++ ones. I think that it's indeed interesting to know why.

I profiled the Go client and server with the `pprof` and found out that `syscall.Syscall` takes 70% of the total execution time. According to [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19563) ticket, in Go syscalls are approximately 1.4 times slower than in C.

```
(pprof) top -cum
Showing nodes accounting for 18.78s, 67.97% of 27.63s total
Dropped 44 nodes (cum <= 0.14s)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 44
  flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
 0.11s   0.4%   0.4%     22.65s 81.98%  main.main
     0     0%   0.4%     22.65s 81.98%  runtime.main
18.14s 65.65% 66.05%     19.91s 72.06%  syscall.Syscall
 0.03s  0.11% 66.16%     12.91s 46.72%  net.(*conn).Read
 0.10s  0.36% 66.52%     12.88s 46.62%  net.(*netFD).Read
 0.16s  0.58% 67.10%     12.78s 46.25%  internal/poll.(*FD).Read
 0.06s  0.22% 67.32%     11.87s 42.96%  syscall.Read
 0.11s   0.4% 67.72%     11.81s 42.74%  syscall.read
 0.02s 0.072% 67.79%      9.30s 33.66%  net.(*conn).Write
 0.05s  0.18% 67.97%      9.28s 33.59%  net.(*netFD).Write
```

I gradually decreased the number of `Conn.Write` and `Conn.Read` calls and increased the size of the buffer accordingly, so that the number of transferred bytes stayed the same. The result is that the fewer these calls the program makes, the closer its performance to the C++ version.